# Angular radio buttons are not checked correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, and they should be checked depending on some condition.

```
<input data-ng-checked="user.contract1 || user.contract2" data-ng-model="user.agreed" type="radio" data-ng-value="true"> Yes
<input data-ng-checked="!user.contract1 && !user.contract2" data-ng-model="user.agreed" type="radio" data-ng-value="false"> No
```

So here, we have a model `user.agreed` which holds true/false depending on whether that user has agreed:

- If the user has agreed to either contract, then `user.agreed = true`
- If the user has not agreed to either contract, then `user.agreed = false`

I have noticed that when I load the page, the radio button is sometimes selected on 'No' instead of 'Yes'. I think this has to do with the digest cycle completing before my data has loaded from the server.

But I thought doing this would be two-way binding, so if the `user` model changes, the view will change. When data gets loaded from the server, the model gets updated with the new info, and so the view should reflect this  change.

But that's not happening. How can I force `ng-checked` to reflect my model changes?

**EDIT**
controller code:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', ["QueryService", function(QueryService) {

    $scope.user = {
        contract1 = false;
        contactt2 = false;
    };


    QueryService.getUser().success(function(user) {
        $scope.user = user;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue could be because of `ng-checked` along with `ng-model`. You cannot use both of them together. Using `ng-checked` will not set the value of `ng-model`, it will just set the `checked` property on the element. Instead of using ng-checked set the value of ng-model instead and use same `name` for radio button so that they act as a group.

You could just do:

```
<input name="agree" data-ng-model="user.agreed" type="radio" data-ng-value="true"> Yes
<input name="agree" data-ng-model="user.agreed" type="radio" data-ng-value="false"> No
```

and set initial value

```
 user.agreed = user.contract1 || user.contract2; //Or whatever initial value
```